# Problems tracing file and line for debug logging (PHP)

Tags: php, debugging, backtrace

So I am trying to make a method that allows for logging debug messages on the fly, and I would like to include the file name and line number where the message occured. My first inclination was to give debug_backtrace() as one of the arguments for the logging method, which returns an array which contains the current file name and line number.

The problem is, this only gives the file and line of the very first file called (index.php). index.php is only a five line file that calls a method from a class in an included file however, so the line and file information always say (index.php, line 5) no matter what and are useless.

Is there a way to get the current line and file no matter where in the code you are?

**Addition**

Here is the file and line info:

> [2011-01-23 06:26:10] Information:
>   "Request made for non-existant
>   controller (test).", File:
>   "/home/spotless/public_html/mymvc/index.php",
>   Line: 5, Request: "/test"

Here is the index.php in its entirety:

```
<?php

    include_once('application/init.php');
    lev_init::init();
?>
```

Here is the logging call using the debug_backtrace(), within the init.php file (line 37):

```
// if requested controller does not exist, log
lev_logging::message('Request made for non-existant controller ('.$requested_controller.').', debug_backtrace());
```

**second update**

var_dump of debug_backtrace

> array(1) { [0]=> array(6) { ["file"]=>
>   string(42)
>   "/home/spotless/public_html/mymvc/index.php"
>   ["line"]=> int(5) ["function"]=>
>   string(4) "init" ["class"]=> string(8)
>   "lev_init" ["type"]=> string(2) "::"
>   ["args"]=> array(0) { } } }

Comment: That shouldn't be. A backtrace should contain the full info. Are you aware it is an array ? Can you show an example backtrace?

Comment: @dqhendricks: are you sure the documentation shows that it show the current line and file for every function call ....

Comment: From your description this rather calls for the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` constants.

Comment: @Pekka @RageZ @mario added additional info. mario, i do not want to have two arguments for this call instead of one, plus I may utilize the other elements within the trace array at some point.

Comment: Do a `print_r()` on the array, there should be more info in there than just that

Comment: You can just use `$i = debug_backtrace();` in your log function. The last execution position would always be in `$i[1]`. Which will however be empty if you invoked the log function from the global scope.

Comment: @Pekka @RageZ @mario add var dump of the debug_backtrace... the array only contains one element which has the info I was printing. Is this supposed to contain more elements?

Comment: @dqhendricks: depends where you are calling it ... but yes it contains the full stack trace apart if you found a bug in PHP. can you give us some more details where the lev_logging::message is located ...

Comment: @dqhendricks: I am wondering if actually are not confused about the meaning of stack trace.

Comment: @Pekka @RageZ the lev_logging::message is called from inside a static method of the lev_init class. you can see where this static method is called in my description of the index.php file.

Comment: @dqhendricks: so since you call it from the index.php the stack only have the call from the index.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) returns an array so do a `var_export(debug_backtrace(), true)`

i.e.:

```
// if requested controller does not exist, log
lev_logging::message('Request made for non-existant controller ('.$requested_controller.').', var_export(debug_backtrace(), true));
```

Note:

just and edit what what/where the stack trace matters.

```
<?php
// filename: /tmp/a.php

function b_test($foo)
{
   var_dump(debug_backtrace());
}

function a_test($str)
{
    echo "\nHi: $str";
    b_test('bar');
    var_dump(debug_backtrace());
}

a_test('friend');
?>

<?php
// filename: /tmp/b.php
include_once '/tmp/a.php';
```

?>

The debug_backtrace in b_test will show everything up to the include. the one in a_test won't show the b_test call since it has returned...

Answer (score 2):

If you are in the global context with this, not a function, then what you show is normal behaviour. The inclusion of files does **not** reflect in the call stack - only the calling of functions and methods.

As far as I know, there is no way to build an "include trace", a list of the nested includes a line of code is in. This has been asked repeatedly on SO, and IIRC, a solution was never found.

Comment: Does this mean that if I call the debug_backtrace from within the logging function, it would get the line that the logging function was called?

Comment: @dqhendricks yup, and only that line (if it's in the global context).

Comment: i did it within the function and it gives me the correct file and line. it's perfect.